# Подскажите пожалуйста почему появляется ошибка. String index out of range: -1

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Hello, friend");
    String s = null;
    System.out.println(sb1.indexOf("f"));//7
    System.out.println(sb1.substring(7, 13));//friend
    s = sb1.append(" How are you?").substring(sb1.indexOf("f", 12));
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sb1.indexOf("f", 12)`  возвращает `-1`. Ну а дальше понятно, что у строки, к которой применяется метод `substring` явно нет позиции `-1`

Comment: Вы не поняли суть текста) У строки нет позиции -1. Всё начинается с нуля. Поэтому `substring` не может взять подстроку с этой отрицательной позиции. Её в принципе не существует у строки. А `sb1.indexOf("f", 12)` именно эту несуществующую позицию вам и возвращает. Получается вот что: `sb1.append(" How are you?").substring(sb1.indexOf(-1);`. Если бы было так `sb1.indexOf("f")` то прокатило бы

Comment: Я только изучаю java, но насколько я понимаю у нас method chaining выглядит следующим образом: сначала к Hello, friend конкатенируем How are you? , а затем сабстринг "выкусывает" с этого предложения String начиная с индекса 7 и заканчивая индексом 12 не включительно. То есть с f по d и на консоль должно вывестись friend. Возможно я что то не правильно написал

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за такой обширный и подробный ответ) Если Вам не сложно - подскажите пожалуйста как вывести на консоль просто friend, а не friend How are you? . Спасибо!

Comment: @Serhii "а затем сабстринг "выкусывает" с этого предложения String начиная с индекса 7 и заканчивая индексом 12 не включительно" --- понял проблему. Вы просто число 12 не там написали. Не в том методе)) Вы его написали в методе `indexOf`, которое вторым аргументом принимает позицию, с которой искать элемент. А вам надо этот аргумент поместить в метод `substring`. Скорее всего вам нужно что-то типа такого: `sb1.append(" How are you?").substring(sb1.indexOf("f"), sb1.indexOf("f") + 6);`

Comment: s = sb1.append(" How are you?").substring(sb1.indexOf("f"),13); Решил вопрос з Вашей помощью) использовал метод substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) Спасибо Вам, Алексей)